# How do I access my own template variables from within a custom template tags template?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am using Django to build a website.

I have a context processor setup that looks something like this:

```
 TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
        ...

    "mysite.context_processors.mystandardvariables"
 )
```

This adds some standard variables that I like to use in templates, such as SITE_NAME and SITE_ROOT.

I have just created my first custom template tag and I find that I cannot access these standard variables.

I don't get any errors and my page displays ok, it's just that the variable that I want are not available.

To check which variables are available I already used `{% debug %}`.

My tag looks like this:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('search/search_snippet.html', takes_context = True)
def search(context):
    form = forms.SearchForm()
    return {'form': form }
```

The template for the tag looks like this:

```
<form action="{{ SITE_ROOT }}search" method="post">
    {% csrf_token  %}
    <table>
        {{ form.as_table }}
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I am including the search tag in my home page like this:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load search_tags %}

{% block content %}

{% search %}

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: And you're sure the keys you're looking for aren't in `context`?

Comment: Thanks, it looks like they are!  I supposed I have to merge my 'form' variable and return 'context'?

Comment: No, you don't have to merge the variables. You should be able to grab the variables in the context by their key, which your inclusion tag can then pick up and do something with, e.g. `context.get('SITE_NAME', None)`

Comment: Yeah I could, but surely that would mean my inclusion tag would have to have 'site specific' knowledge of the variables that are available?  In any case thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Not necessarily. The `None` returned by .get() is what will be returned if they key doesn't exist, so if you wanted to use that template tag on a different project, you could do so without throwing a runtime exception if the key doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, I figured out a way to do what I want using a normal template tag rather than an inclusion tag.

```
@register.tag
def search(parser, token):
    return SearchNode()

class SearchNode(template.Node):
    def render(self, context):
        return render_to_string('search/search_snippet.html', 
                                 { 'form' : forms.FindForm() }, context)
```

Here I am passing the context through to the function that renders my template to a string.

I would have preferred to implement this as an inclusion tag as it seems like less work, but I wasn't sure how to get it to work.

If anyone knows how to get this working with an inclusion tag please answer and I'll mark your question as the right answer.